# Access a Class property within the static method by "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, events, binding, es6-class, decoupling

Hey guys i started reading about Javascript ES6 classes so was trying out something

Here is my ProductItem class which render each product

```
class ProductItem {
  constructor(product) {
    this.product = product;
  }
  addToCart() {
    console.log("adding product to cart", this.product);
    ShoppingCart.addProduct(this.product);
  }
  render() {
    const prodEl = document.createElement("li");
    prodEl.className = "product-item";
    prodEl.innerHTML = `
      <div>
        <img src="${this.product.imageUrl}" alt="${this.product.title}" >
        <div class="product-item__content">
          <h2>${this.product.title}</h2>
          <h3>\$${this.product.price}</h3>
          <p>${this.product.description}</p>
          <button>Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
    const addCardButton = prodEl.querySelector("button");
    addCardButton.addEventListener("click", this.addToCart.bind(this));
    return prodEl;
  }
}
```

In another class we loop and instantiate this class  like

```
for (const prod of this.products) {
      const productItem = new ProductItem(prod);
      const prodEl = productItem.render();
      prodList.append(prodEl);
    }
```

So now the problem is that i made another class called "ShoppingCart" to add products to cart when i click on button so thats like

```
class ShoppingCart {
  constructor(items){
    console.log(this)
    this.items=items
  }
  static addProduct(product) {
    console.log(this);
    this.items.push(product);
    this.totalOutput = `<h2>Total Amount: ${1}</h2>`;
  }


}
```

as i read static method can be called without Instantiating class
so what i did was when i click on button in my "ProductItem" class
i called a fn() and then u can see in that function what i did was

```
addToCart() {
    console.log("adding product to cart", this.product);
    ShoppingCart.addProduct(this.product);
  }
```

But this gives me error that

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

and also when i console "this" in addProduct i see something weird as output

```
> class ShoppingCart {   constructor(items){
>     console.log(this)
>     this.items=items   }   static addProduct(product) {
>     console.log(this);
>     this.items.push(product);
>     this.totalOutput = `<h2>Tot…........
```

Comment: A product item has to be entirely agnostic to where it will be added to. Thus the prototypal `addToCart` method is of no use, it's even misleading. One needs to find another modeling approach. I start thinking about it ...

Comment: yeah the approach aint good cause i am following a tutorial and he is just uisng so many classes to explain some more concepts... well can u let me know what woud be the best approach ??

Comment: are there any questions left?

Comment: @PeterSeliger no mate thanks a lot for detailed explaination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `this.items.push(product)` tries to push a product into `this.items`, however you never initialize `this.items` so its value is `undefined`. The constructor is only executed when you create a new instances of a class, but not for the class itself.

To solve the problem you have to define a static `items` property on `ShoppingCart`:

```
class ShoppingCart {
  static items = [];

  static addProduct(product) {
    this.items.push(product);
    this.totalOutput = `<h2>Total Amount: ${1}</h2>`;
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case `ShoppingCart` was just degraded to a namespace, no need at all for a *class* then. Any approach that gets rid of the static `addProduct` and makes the letter an instance method might be more helpful, since webpages tend to have rendered more than just one view representative of a shopping cart at the time.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Yes `ShoppingCart` is basically a namespace at this point. I'm not trying to write the best possible solution here. I'm trying to point out what went wrong with the code of OP, so they can learn from their mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The base approach for this kind of problem is *decoupling modules or dependencies (across such modules) via events* in order to implement each module in the most dump/agnostic/clean possible way.

For the OP's example code this answer is somehow misusing the `document` as *event bus* for [custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent).

An *event bus* for channeling model data does not necessarily need to be part of the *DOM*. One should feel encouraged to build such an abstraction oneself or to make use of one of the many available libraries which provide such utility/functionality.

Personally I was still not pleased with how the modules are structured for there is still a too wild mix of model and view related code within e.g. the shopping cart module. But the *decoupling* is the very base one can work ones way towards even cleaner code.

But what also should be clear by now ... any approach that gets rid of the static `addProduct` (... a method pinned directly to the `ShoppingCart` namespace has no chance of ever accessing a `ShoppingCart` instance via `this` ...) and makes the letter an instance method, might be of more help, since webpages tend to have rendered more than just one view representative of a *shopping cart* at the time.

```js
// e.g. module ... view/ShoppingCart.js

/*export */function handleAddProductToBoundCart(evt) {
  const shoppingCart = this;
  shoppingCart.addProduct(evt.detail.product);
}

/*export */class ShoppingCart {
  constructor(elmRoot, items) {
    this.elmRoot = elmRoot;
    this.items = items;
    this.renderItemCount();
  }
  renderItemCount() {
    this.elmRoot.innerHTML = `<h2>Total Amount: ${ this.items.length }</h2>`;
  }
  addProduct(product) {
    this.items.push(product);
    this.renderItemCount();

    console.log('ShoppingCart :: addProduct :: product :', product);
  }
  
}
// -----


// e.g. module ... view/ProductItem.js

function handleAddBoundProductItem() {
  const productItem = this;
  const customEvent = new CustomEvent("addtocart", { detail: { product: productItem } });
  document.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
}

/*export */class ProductItem { 
  constructor(product) {
    this.product = product;
  }
  render() {
    const prodEl = document.createElement("li");
    prodEl.className = "product-item";
    prodEl.innerHTML = `
      <div>
        <img src="${this.product.imageUrl}" alt="${this.product.title}" >
        <div class="product-item__content">
          <h2>${this.product.title}</h2>
          <h3>\$${this.product.price}</h3>
          <p>${this.product.description}</p>
          <button>Add to Cart</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
    const addCardButton = prodEl.querySelector("button");
    addCardButton.addEventListener("click", handleAddBoundProductItem.bind(this));
    return prodEl;
  }
}
// -----


// some product list model data from wherever it came from ...

const productList = [{
  imageUrl: '',
  title: 'Product A',
  price: '12.30 Currency',
  description: 'best whatsoever'
}, {
  imageUrl: '',
  title: 'Product B',
  price: '450.00 Currency',
  description: 'most expensive'
}];
// -----


// render functionality from yet another view module ...

// ... import statements ...

const cartView = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(cartView);

const shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart(cartView, []);
document.addEventListener('addtocart', handleAddProductToBoundCart.bind(shoppingCart));

// ...
// ...

const prodListView = document.createElement('ul');
document.body.appendChild(prodListView)

//for (const prod of this.products) {
for (const product of productList) {

  const productItem = new ProductItem(product);
  const prodEl = productItem.render();

  // prodList.append(prodEl);

  prodListView.append(prodEl);
}

// additional cart, just in order to demonstrate the appoache's capabilities ...

const miniCartView = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(miniCartView);

const miniCart = new ShoppingCart(miniCartView, []);
document.addEventListener('addtocart', handleAddProductToBoundCart.bind(miniCart));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%!important;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  left: auto!important;
  bottom: auto!important;
}


h2, h3, p, ul, button {
  font-size: .85em;
  margin: 1px 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: .7em;
}
li {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```